# how to write output of command "adb push file.txt /sdcard/" to text file?

Tags: perl, command-line, batch-file, adb

Command :

```
adb push test.mp4 /sdcard/test.mp4
```

output of command :

```
2717 KB/s (17104177 bytes in 6.146s)
```

i want to write above output in one text file.

i tried following command :

```
adb push test.mp4 /sdcard/test.mp4 > Result.txt
```

but still Result.txt file is blank.

Please help, if you have any idea !!!

if solution is with using perl or python then also it is ok for me.

Comment: try adb shell, then push test.mp4 /sdcard/test.mp4 > Result.txt

Comment: Dear Keale, inside "adb shell", there is no "push" command.

Comment: at the end of the line add  2>&1 and see if you get the text in the result.txt file.

Comment: thanks, addition of "2>&1" at the end of line is working for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using bash, you can redirect `stderr` :

```
adb push test.mp4 /sdcard/test.mp4 2> Result.txt
```

or both `stdout` and `stderr` :

```
adb push test.mp4 /sdcard/test.mp4 > Result.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks, this command "adb push test.mp4 /sdcard/test.mp4 > Result.txt 2>&1" is works for me with perfection.